# Forms Authentication Cookie is not setting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I am trying to use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username,true,cookiepath);`
On using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` it's redirecting to the `DefaultUrl` provided in the web.config.

**Authentication section in web.config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".ASPXADMINAUTH" 
               loginUrl="/Default.aspx" 
               defaultUrl="homepage.aspx"
               protection="All"
              timeout="30" path="/admin" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" cookieless="UseCookies" domain="localhost" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework20" ></forms>
</authentication>
```

**In httpModules Section:**

```
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
```

The page is redirecting from the Loginpage to the "homepage.aspx" but it didn't set the Authentication cookie.

In my **Response header**, **Set-Cookie** contains the Authentication cookie, but it is not set in the homepage.aspx page.

So the LoginStaus and LoginName control is not working.

Comment: It sounds like you are accessing your site through a different domain name than you are setting the cookie for.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Thanx for your reply. In my code i am using the domain as "http://localhost:51370" and I also checked by removing the domain attribute. But didn't work.

Comment: Are all your pages located under `/admin`? Because if they are not, you should change the `path` attribute to `/`.

Comment: what is the use of domain..? is there difference between /admin and /..?

Comment: If you set a cookie for `domain=localhost` and `path=/admin` your browser will only send that cookie to the server when accessing a resource on that domain and with the right path, e.g. `http://localhost/admin/somepage.aspx`. It will not send to cookie to the server if you access `http://localhost/Default.aspx` because the path doesn't match. Same thing goes for the domain. If you set a cookie for `localhost` but later access the server through an alias such as `mydevserver` the browser will not send the cookie either.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen My login page is "http://localhost:51370/Default.aspx" and after login the cookie has to be set in "http://localhost:51370/my-homepage.aspx". I wrote the domain: domain="http://localhost:51370/"  and path: path="/" is that right? My LoginStatus and LoginName controls not working.

Comment: Are you setting cookies programmatically ??If yes, show the code

Comment: @FlopScientist I am not setting it programmatically. I am just using  Session["user"] = "username"; and then  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true,FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath); in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The problems in your code are `path="/admin" domain="localhost"`

### According to your code

After user logins, a cookie is set under /admin. As the result, every pages under /admin folder knows that the user is authenticated such as ~/admin/default.aspx.

However ~/homepage.aspx does not know about user, because ~/homepage.aspx cannot read cookie written under /admin.

```
var path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("win", false, path);
```

### How to fix it?

You want to start slowly using simple one. Then tweak depending on what you need.

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/homepage.aspx" />
```

FYI: Please do not add properties which are default such as `slidingExpiration="true"`, 
`enableCrossAppRedirects="false"` and so on.